# how to solveCurrent location problem react native

Tags: react-native, google-maps

When clicking on "Use my current location", it writes on text input "Use my current location" and nothing seems to happen.

Normal autocomplete queries works perfectly.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
       placeholder={LocalizedStrings.search}
       minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
       autoFocus={false}
       textInputProps={{
         onChangeText: (text) => {
           if (!text.length) {
            this.address = '';
            this.latlng = null;
           } 
         }
       }}
       returnKeyType={'search'}
       listViewDisplayed={'auto'}
       fetchDetails={true}
       renderDescription={row => row.description || row.vicinity}
       onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        console.log(data, details);
        if (details && details.formatted_address) {
          this.address = details.formatted_address;
        }
        if (details && details.geometry && details.geometry.location) {
          this.latlng = details.geometry.location;
        }
       }}
       getDefaultValue={() => ''}
       query={{
         key: 'my_key',
         language: 'es', // language of the results
         types: 'geocode' // default: 'geocode'
       }}
       styles={{
         textInputContainer: {
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderTopWidth: 0
         },
         textInput: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          fontFamily: Fonts.regular,
          color: Colors.gray_regular
         },
         description: {
           fontFamily: Fonts.bold,
           color: Colors.gray_bold
         },
         predefinedPlacesDescription: {
           color: Colors.accent_color
         }
       }}
       currentLocation={true}
       currentLocationLabel={LocalizedStrings.current_location}
       nearbyPlacesAPI={'GooglePlacesSearch'}
       GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
         // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
       }}
       GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
         // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
         rankby: 'distance'
       }}
       filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
       debounce={200}
       renderLeftButton={()  => {}}
       renderRightButton={() => {}}
     />
```

I logged, it has data, but it not display in screen. It just display lines like image below.

anyone help me thanks

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Your image is not attached. What are you seeing?